# enumerateExports missing functions

Tags: frida

```
Module.enumerateExports("libgame.so", { onMatch: function(e) { 

console.log("type " + e.type + " name of function = " + e.name + " " +    e.address); }
, onComplete: function() { } });
```

it does not list all the functions and variables wich im 100% sure some of them are being used after taking a look at ida pro , also there is two odex files in the app user folder , base.odex and some generated odex name based on timestamp , can `enumerateloadedClasses` load the other odex file or just the base.odex ? im thinking maybe some of the library code is being dumped as odex then calling DynamiteLoaderClassLoader to load it , also the addresses provided does not much ida for exemple on frida i get 0xc32bcf64 but the function on ida its 0x25E4F64

Comment: `enumerateloadedClasses` AFAIK directly access the class list available in the JVM. hence if a DEX file has been loaded the classes should be available. However non-standard dex files as you have encountered may be loaded some time after app start.

Comment: Regarding the function start address: Have to substracted the library base address from the address you got from Frida? Because of ASLR the library base address usually changes every time you run the app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549616

Comment: @Robert thanks for the reply , as i suspected ; enumerateExports does not hook the app and catch all the calls to the module , it just enumerates public classes from the library , the address problem is not the biggest one , on the other hand listing all the functions with the right pointer is !

Comment: @Robert i think i will try the stalker , i need something that really monitors all the calls to the library